# How to get total page view count from google analytics in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am sending page view count to google analytics using the following code,

```
function gaInit() {
  $.getScript('//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'); // jQuery shortcut
  window.ga = window.ga || function () { (ga.q = ga.q || []).push(arguments) }; ga.l = +new Date;
  ga('create', 'UA-<ID>', 'auto');

  console.log("Initalized");
  return ga;
};

function gaTrack(path, title) {
  var track =  { page: path, title: title};

  ga = window.ga || gaInit();

  ga('set', track);
  ga('send', 'pageview');

  console.log("Tracked");
};

$(window).load(function(){
    console.log("Inside ga load function");
    var unique_id = $('#unique_id').text();
    var url     = /view/ + unique_id
    gaTrack(url, "View");
});
```

I have to display the total views in the web page similar to how stackoverflow shows the post views. How can I get the total views from ga through api?

Could someone help me with this? I am fairly new to Jquery and ga.

Comment: Here is the [google analytics javascript api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/web-js#enable) read this , try it and if you will have a specific question, ask..

Comment: @MoshFeu That requires a login via oAuth so it won't work for users who do not have access to the GA account in the first place. I do not think that's what the OP wants and I do not think what he want's even possibly with a 100% javascript solution (he needs either at least a teeny serverside bit to set up authentication or he might use one of the commercial services that allow for embedding GA data).